# Add a prefix and suffix to each row of a dataframe but no suffix to the last row and then collapse all

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe of values which I need append a prefix and suffix to each row **expect** for the last row where I do not wish to add the suffix but do the prefix.

I then need to collapse this dataframe to a single string so that I can pass it into a SQL query.

My data looks like follows:

```
x <- data.frame(products = c("foo","bar","foobar"))
```

I need to append `"BRAND_NAME LIKE '%"` as the prefix and `"%' OR"` as the suffix and then collapse so that my string looks like:

```
"BRAND_NAME LIKE '%foo%' OR BRAND_NAME LIKE '%bar%' OR BRAND_NAME LIKE '%foobar%'"
```

Please note that I need to exclude the **"OR"** at the end of the last element.

I have tried using the glue package but have not found a way to just apply the prefix to the last row

```
x %>% mutate(new_string = glue("BRAND_NM LIKE '%{products}%' OR"))
```

I have also tried the str_remove function but I am concerned that some of my products will contain "OR" in their names and it will mess up my analysis.

```
str_remove(tail(products,1), " OR")
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best approach is to add prefix and suffix to all,
then extract the string to remove the last OR

`library(tidyverse)`
`library(glue)`

`x <- data.frame(products = c("foo","bar","foobar"))`

`x$products <-  glue("BRAND_NAME LIKE '% {x$products} %' OR ")`

now collapse to single string

`glue_collapse(x$products) %>%`

now the string extraction

`str_extract(., ".+(?= OR $)")`

This last statement looks ahead for the space-OR-space at the end ($) for a match, and includes all characters up to but not including this match

Comment: thanks for the reply, this works great when I run the code like you have above (broken out into separate lines) but when I try to pipe it together it complains of "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" . The code i am running is as follows: x <- data.frame(products = c("foo","bar","foobar")) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(products = glue::glue("BRAND_NM LIKE '%{products}%' OR ")) %>% 
  glue::glue_collapse(x$products) %>% 
  stringr::str_extract(., ".+(?= OR $)")

Comment: To make this a pure pipe workflow, you can do this without the `$`   `library(tidyverse) 
library(glue)

x <- data.frame(products = c("foo","bar","foobar")) %>% 
  mutate(products = glue("BRAND_NAME LIKE '% {products} %' OR ")) %>% 
  glue_collapse() %>% 
  str_extract("BRAND.+(?= OR )")

x`

Answer (score 1):

Basesd on your expected output, this might probably be what you are looking for:

```
paste0( "BRANDNAME LIKE ", paste0( "'%", x$products, "%'", collapse = " OR BRANDNAME LIKE ") )

#[1] "BRANDNAME LIKE '%foo%' OR BRANDNAME LIKE '%bar%' OR BRANDNAME LIKE '%foobar%'"
```